# Adding caption to this jquery slider code

Tags: jquery, slider, caption

I have the following script which is a simple slider and works fine.

```
var current_img = 1;
var i;

$(document).ready(function(){
var imgs = $("#image").find("img"); 


function show_img(){
  for (i = 1; i < imgs.length+1; i++) {
    if(i == current_img){
      $(imgs[i-1]).show()

    }else{
      $(imgs[i-1]).hide()

    }
  }
}

$("#prev").click(function(){
  if(current_img == 1){
    current_img = imgs.length;
  }else{
    current_img = current_img - 1
  }
  show_img();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
  if(current_img == imgs.length){
    current_img = 1;
  }else{
    current_img = current_img + 1
  }
  show_img();
});
```

});

I would like to add a line or two of text to each image how do I do this?  Currently I have the all the images in a single div id #images but haven't got a clue how to modify it so that I can select both img and span or text.

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake 'code'<div id="image">
    
              <img src="/app/file/asset/0ED4354F200303FCAD7B0FBD33303E0BA6FE800C90375131/" alt="image1"><img src="/app/file/asset/10586DC92003006DF307BF991A31390B4FCC3BFC65F9861A/" alt="image2" hidden="true"></div>